# To find $f(\{z\in \mathbb{C}:0<|z|<\varepsilon\})$ if $f(z)=\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Let $\varepsilon>0$. I want to find the image of $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<\varepsilon\}$ 
through of $f(z)=\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$. I know that $f\left(\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<\varepsilon\}\right)=\mathbb{C}$ using Picard's theorem but, How can I show this directly?

I have shown direcly that the image of $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<\varepsilon\}$ throught of $g(z)=e^\frac{1}{z}$ is $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Is it useful?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{|z|>R\}$ is a base of (punctured, if you work in $\mathbb{C}$) neighbourhood of $\infty$, any neighbourhood of $\infty$ contains a strip $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re z\in [a,a+2\pi]\}$.

The desired result now follows from periodicity and surjectivity of $\cos\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.